# Are the poles of the following transfer function correct?

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

$ H(s) = \frac{M_2p}{M_1(M_1M_2s^4 + M_1ps^2 + M_2ps^2)}$

Poles :   ${  s^2(M_1M_2s^2 + M_1p + M_2p)} = 0$

${  s ^2 = \frac{-p(M_1+M_2)}{(M_1M_2)}}$

${  s= \sqrt{\frac{-p(M_1+M_2)}{(M_1M_2)}}}$ and ${  s = 0}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but if you want to list all poles, then you should also add,

$$
s = -\sqrt{\frac{-p(M_1+M_2)}{M_1\,M_2}}
$$

and mention that $s=0$ has a multiplicity of two.